# Google Ads API: batch-processing vs bulk mutates

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client, ads-api

I want to remove a few ads in one server request.
What is the difference between:

- batch-processing (only async?)
- bulk mutates (only sync, shorter code?)

I have tried both ways and got errors:

1. batch-processing

I've tried to follow this [post](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/batch-processing/flow) about `batch-processing` to create an async batch job for removing multiple ads. It was sent to the server, but I didn't see the sent ad ids were deleted.

Do I miss anything?

```
class ServiceWrapper:
    """Wraps GoogleAdsService API request"""

    # public properties ...

    def __init__(self, client, customer_id):
        self._client = client
        self._ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
        self._ad_group_ad_service = client.get_service("AdGroupAdService")
        self._batch_job_service = client.get_service("BatchJobService")
        self._customer_id = customer_id

        self._batch_job_operation = self._create_batch_job_operation(client)
        self._batch_job_resource_name = self._create_batch_job(self._batch_job_service, customer_id,
                                                               self._batch_job_operation)

    def _create_batch_job_operation(self, client):
        """Created a BatchJobOperation and sets an empty BatchJob instance to
        the "create" property in order to tell the Google Ads API that we're
        creating a new BatchJob.
        Args:
            client: an initialized GoogleAdsClient instance.
        Returns: a BatchJobOperation with a BatchJob instance set in the "create"
            property.
        """
        batch_job_operation = client.get_type("BatchJobOperation")
        batch_job = client.get_type("BatchJob")
        client.copy_from(batch_job_operation.create, batch_job)
        return batch_job_operation

    def _create_batch_job(self, batch_job_service, customer_id, batch_job_operation):
        """Creates a batch job for the specified customer ID.
        Args:
            batch_job_service: an instance of the BatchJobService message class.
            customer_id: a str of a customer ID.
            batch_job_operation: a BatchJobOperation instance set to "create"
        Returns: a str of a resource name for a batch job.
        """
        try:
            response = batch_job_service.mutate_batch_job(
                customer_id=customer_id, operation=batch_job_operation
            )
            resource_name = response.result.resource_name
            print(f'Created a batch job with resource name "{resource_name}"')
            return resource_name
        except GoogleAdsException as exception:
            handle_googleads_exception(exception)

    def add_all_batch_job_operations(self, batch_job_service, operations, resource_name):
        """Adds all mutate operations to the batch job.
        As this is the first time for this batch job, we pass null as a sequence
        token. The response will contain the next sequence token that we can use
        to upload more operations in the future.
        Args:
            batch_job_service: an instance of the BatchJobService message class.
            operations: a list of a mutate operations.
            resource_name: a str of a resource name for a batch job.
        """
        try:
            response = batch_job_service.add_batch_job_operations(
                resource_name=resource_name,
                sequence_token=None,
                mutate_operations=operations,
            )

            print(
                f"{response.total_operations} mutate operations have been "
                "added so far."
            )

            # You can use this next sequence token for calling
            # add_batch_job_operations() next time.
            print(
                "Next sequence token for adding next operations is "
                f"{response.next_sequence_token}"
            )
        except GoogleAdsException as exception:
            handle_googleads_exception(exception)


def remove_disapproved_ads_for_account(account):
    """Remove all disapproved ads for a given customer id"""
    ad_removal_operations = []
        for row in rows:
                    ad_removal_operations.append(
                        build_removal_operation(customer_id, ad_json["ad_group_id"],     
    if len(ad_removal_operations) > 0:
        remove_ads(ad_removal_operations)
        #serviceWrapper.mutate(customer_id, [mutate_operation1, mutate_operation2])


def build_removal_operation(customer_id, ad_group_id, ad_id):
    """Removes the specified ad"""
    resource_name = serviceWrapper.ad_group_ad_service.ad_group_ad_path(
        customer_id, ad_group_id, ad_id
    )
    ad_group_ad_operation = serviceWrapper.client.get_type("AdGroupAdOperation")
    ad_group_ad_operation.remove = resource_name
    return ad_group_ad_operation

async def remove_ads(removal_operations):
    """Removes the specified ad"""
    serviceWrapper.add_all_batch_job_operations(serviceWrapper.batch_job_service, removal_operations,
                                                serviceWrapper.batch_job_resource_name)
    operations_response = _run_batch_job(serviceWrapper.batch_job_service, serviceWrapper.batch_job_resource_name)

    # Create an asyncio.Event instance to control execution during the
    # asyncronous steps in _poll_batch_job. Note that this is not important
    # for polling asyncronously, it simply helps with execution control so we
    # can run _fetch_and_print_results after the asyncronous operations have
    # completed.
    _done_event = asyncio.Event()
    _poll_batch_job(operations_response, _done_event)
    # Execution will stop here and wait for the asyncronous steps in
    # _poll_batch_job to complete before proceeding.
    await _done_event.wait()
    _fetch_and_print_results(serviceWrapper.client, serviceWrapper.batch_job_service,
                             serviceWrapper.batch_job_resource_name)


def _run_batch_job(batch_job_service, resource_name):
    """Runs the batch job for executing all uploaded mutate operations.
    Args:
        batch_job_service: an instance of the BatchJobService message class.
        resource_name: a str of a resource name for a batch job.
    Returns: a google.api_core.operation.Operation instance.
    """
    try:
        response = batch_job_service.run_batch_job(resource_name=resource_name)
        print(
            f'Batch job with resource name "{resource_name}" has been '
            "executed."
        )
        return response
    except GoogleAdsException as exception:
        handle_googleads_exception(exception)


def _poll_batch_job(operations_response, event):
    """Polls the server until the batch job execution finishes.
    Sets the initial poll delay time and the total time to wait before time-out.
    Args:
        operations_response: a google.api_core.operation.Operation instance.
        event: an instance of asyncio.Event to invoke once the operations have
            completed, alerting the awaiting calling code that it can proceed.
    """
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def _done_callback(future):
        # The operations_response object will call callbacks from a daemon
        # thread so we must use a threadsafe method of setting the event here
        # otherwise it will not trigger the awaiting code.
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(event.set)

    # operations_response represents a Long-Running Operation or LRO. The class
    # provides an interface for polling the API to check when the operation is
    # complete. Below we use the asynchronous interface, but there's also a
    # synchronous interface that uses the Operation.result method.
    # See: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operation.html
    operations_response.add_done_callback(_done_callback)


def _fetch_and_print_results(client, batch_job_service, resource_name):
    """Prints all the results from running the batch job.
    Args:
        client: an initialized GoogleAdsClient instance.
        batch_job_service: an instance of the BatchJobService message class.
        resource_name: a str of a resource name for a batch job.
    """
    print(
        f'Batch job with resource name "{resource_name}" has finished. '
        "Now, printing its results..."
    )

    list_results_request = client.get_type("ListBatchJobResultsRequest")
    list_results_request.resource_name = resource_name
    list_results_request.page_size = BULK_REMOVE_PAGE_SIZE
    # Gets all the results from running batch job and prints their information.
    batch_job_results = batch_job_service.list_batch_job_results(
        request=list_results_request
    )

    for batch_job_result in batch_job_results:
        status = batch_job_result.status.message
        status = status if status else "N/A"
        result = batch_job_result.mutate_operation_response
        result = result or "N/A"
        print(
            f"Batch job #{batch_job_result.operation_index} "
            f'has a status "{status}" and response type "{result}"'
        )
        # [END add_complete_campaigns_using_batch_job_4]
```

2. Bulk Mutates

If I choose to follow this [post](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/mutating/bulk-mutate) about `Bulk Mutates`, and create a sync batch, I get an undefined symbol `:Mutate` how can I fix this? Or make this code work?

```
class ServiceWrapper:
    """Wraps GoogleAdsService API request"""

    # public properties ...

    def __init__(self, client, customer_id):
        self._client = client
        self._ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
        self._ad_group_ad_service = client.get_service("AdGroupAdService")
        self._batch_job_service = client.get_service("BatchJobService")
        self._customer_id = customer_id

        self._batch_job_operation = self._create_batch_job_operation(client)
        self._batch_job_resource_name = self._create_batch_job(self._batch_job_service, customer_id,
                                                               self._batch_job_operation)

       

 def build_removal_operation_sync(customer_id, ad_group_id, ad_id):
     mutate_operation1 = serviceWrapper.client.operation(:Mutate)

     """Removes the specified ad"""
     resource_name = serviceWrapper.ad_group_ad_service.ad_group_ad_path(
         customer_id, ad_group_id, ad_id
     )
     ad_group_ad_operation = serviceWrapper.client.get_type("AdGroupAdOperation")
     ad_group_ad_operation.remove = resource_name

     mutate_operation1.ad_group_ad_operation = campaign_operation
```